# customer name is not showing in header after customer programatically logged in

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to log in customer automatically when user redirects to the website from different website. I am able to log in customer but after customer logged in automatically customer name is not showing in header.

code to login customer

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
Use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class Login extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        RequestInterface $request,
        Curl $curl,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerModel,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_curl = $curl;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   

 public function execute()
    {
...
$customerObj = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($custID);
$this->session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customerObj);
...

$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
 $resultRedirect->setPath('/');
   return $resultRedirect;

}
}
```

Comment: can you add the code that shows the customer's name in the header? Also, where do you invoke your login code?

Comment: I am using default header.phtml file for header. I have write code in controller where i filter the customer collection and get the ID and login that customer.

Comment: ok, so the customer name is loaded using knockout js? what class does the $session property have? is it the same class used in Magento_Customer module? Have you tried loading the customer via Repository (as is recommended) instead of using the factory?

Comment: I have updated the question please have look

Comment: I'd try to look into `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost`. It's doing some stuff with the cookies after login. Also, make sure the customer name is really generated via knockout js and NOT php. If it is generated using PHP, most likely the full page cache is the problem here